# Local coordinates for Cylinders

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Suppose point $A$ has intrinsic local coordinarcs of $(0,0)$ on a cylinder of radius $7$ and point $B$ has intrinsic local coordinarcs of $(6 \pi,4)$. Find two angles that spiral geodesics could form with the great circle through point $A$ and indicate the number of times that spiral goes completely around the cylinder.

Since the radius of the cylinder is $7$ units , the circumference $C$ of the great circle passing through point $A$ is $C= 2 \pi(7)=14 \pi$. Now ,

$\alpha= arctan(\frac{h}{d+nC})$ where $n=0,1,2,.....$

First angle 
When $n=0$

$\alpha=arctan(\frac{4}{6\pi+0 \times (14 \pi)})$ which approx. $0.209$ radiant

Second angle 
when $n=1$

$\alpha=arctan(\frac{4}{6\pi+1 \times (14 \pi)})$ which approx. $0.635$ 
radiant

Now, first of all , would someone verify that for me. And tell me how would I indicate the number of times that spiral goes completely around the cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

the question is asking you just to indicate how many times does the spiral geodesic goes completely around the cylinder. You don't have to find out the exact number of times a spiral geodesic can go (because it can be infinite) just specify the number of times it goes when you find the two angles. For example, 
when n = 0, specify that the spiral geodesic does not go completely around the cylinder.
when n= 1, specify that the spiral geodesic goes completely around the cylinder for one time.
By the way, your answer 0.635 is wrong(might be a typo) it should be 0.0635.